# Using premium primitives?

Tags: featuretools

How do I use the premium primitives like IsFreeEmailDomain, AgeOver25 etc?
I get an error when I try to import the premium ones:

> > > > from featuretools.primitives import IsFreeEmailDomain
> > > >         Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > >           File "", line 1, in 
> > > >         ImportError: cannot import name 'IsFreeEmailDomain'

Answer (score 1):

Premium Primitives do not come preinstalled in the open source version of Featuretools. These primitives are included in the enterprise version. You can visit [featurelabs.com](https://www.featurelabs.com/featuretools/?__hstc=166560673.424a6c68f1d69eeaf4804490b2d5589c.1580135649146.1582589813794.1583335324402.13&__hssc=166560673.3.1583335324402&__hsfp=1118029006) to learn more about Featuretools Enterprise.